# Make div and table header fixed on scroll

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a div where I have a dropdown and then on the bottom there's a table.
I am using ngx-infinite-scrolling, and when I scroll i want the div and the header of the table to remain fixed as more data is added and scrolled down.

This is a jsfiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/348/)

Html code:

```
 <div class="topTable row ">

  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
  <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group" style="width:100%;max-width:200px;">
        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
            <select class="form-control"  >
                <option >All</option>
                <option >Option1</option>
                 <option >Option1</option>
                  <option >Option1</option>
              </select>

        </div>
   </div>


 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-12 tableDiv"  >
  <div class="constrained"  >
  <table class="table table-striped col-md-12 table-condensed cf" >
  <thead class="table-bordered cf">
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
      <th>Column5</th>
      <th>Column6</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr>
      <td > asdf</td>
      <td >asdfa</td>
      <td >fsdf</td>
      <td>sdfsfd</td>
      <td>sdfs</td>
      <td>fsdfsdf</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td > asdf</td>
      <td >asdfa</td>
      <td >fsdf</td>
      <td>sdfsfd</td>
      <td>sdfs</td>
      <td>fsdfsdf</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td > asdf</td>
      <td >asdfa</td>
      <td >fsdf</td>
      <td>sdfsfd</td>
      <td>sdfs</td>
      <td>fsdfsdf</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td > asdf</td>
      <td >asdfa</td>
      <td >fsdf</td>
      <td>sdfsfd</td>
      <td>sdfs</td>
      <td>fsdfsdf</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td > asdf</td>
      <td >asdfa</td>
      <td >fsdf</td>
      <td>sdfsfd</td>
      <td>sdfs</td>
      <td>fsdfsdf</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td > asdf</td>
      <td >asdfa</td>
      <td >fsdf</td>
      <td>sdfsfd</td>
      <td>sdfs</td>
      <td>fsdfsdf</td>
    </tr>

   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
  <div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topTable{
 height:70px;
background:red;
margin-top:-20px;
margin-bottom:20px;     
display: flex;
padding-left: 32px;
border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}

.tableDiv{
margin-top:50px
}
```

I tried putting position:static on the div, but then on scroll down, table would go on top of it.
How to also make table static and its header fixed ?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Position: sticky?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Please consider posting your question with a _[minimal, complete, and verifiable example]_ (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The one you have here is a bit bloated with `asdf`s.

Comment: Ah I apologize. Those were just random content for the rows so that it has enough rows to need to be scrolled down.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **separate the top-block from the content-block**, otherwise you make everything fixed.

Now you can make the first block fixed, the block has to get 100% width and z-index more than the content block (default is 0 -> so we need 1 or higher).

```
position:fixed;
width:100%;
z-index: 1;
```

I have forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n958b7q3/1/
changes are marked.

Some tips:

html

- You got to many divs, only make new div's if really needed
- Your form has no closing tag `</form>`

css:

- You forgot `;` after `border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1)`

Comment: Thank you so much, but this only makes the topDiv fixed. I was trying to also have the table header fixed, that's why I didn't know which positions to use since both need to be fixed on scroll down.

Comment: Sorry, i missunderstood... like this: http://jsfiddle.net/adsrr8ss/ ? You only have to style a little bit more

Comment: Thank you but this won't work because now the header is detached from the table, and if a certain column data has more text and it expands then the header won't do the same. 
Every header column should match the content column, without giving it a fixed width, because I do not know how how long the text will be.